# spring boot actuator custom endpoint does not allow configurable endpoint ID. Example: @Endpoint(id = "${mgmt.id.custom}")

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

spring boot actuator custom endpoint does not allow configurable endpoint. Example: @Endpoint("${mgmt.id.custom}"). Is there any way to fetch endpoint Id from properties file and set it in @Endpoint(id = "Configured From Property file") annotation.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value

Says

> Finally, while you can write a SpEL expression in @Value, such
>   expressions are not processed from application property files.

so I don't think you can do it. However, I remember I did something like

```
a.b=1 
a.b.id=${a.b}
```

before and it worked. so probably you can do this way.

You might able to 1) inject the value from your class' constant variable and then 2) use that constant variable ( with static final keyword on it ) inside of the Endpoint annotation's SpringEL as well.